# Display a dynamic dropdown from custom PHP code inside Elementor Form in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor, acfpro

I need some help and advice in the design of a Event registration form with Wordpress plugin Elementor Pro and ACF Pro.  If these are not suitable, you can recommend any other plugin.

The users may send any number (from 1 to 10+) of delegates to our company event.

How can I collect the company information once, but then repeat the delegate name, age, telephone, email etc. fields to show X number of times (depending on how many delegates they want to register).

Ideally, it would be best if we could ask (Do you have any more people to register?). IF yes, then ask all the input fields for a delegate. If not, then get the form submitted and end.

Further, I want to load the name of the event from a SQL database, and use custom PHP to load the select list dropdown in the same form. Elementor does not seem to be able to do this. Again, once the event is selected, we will want to load the dates for that particular event from the database, via another dropdown/select function that would come from another PHP code.

Is there a way to use Elementor Pro & ACF PRo to create such a form. I need to  have repeatable sections, logic, and also allows for custom php logic/functions to be created to populate select lists, and be able to cascade the dropdowns from the earlier choices, conditionally.

Any help or suggestions are really appreciated. If there is any other Wordpress plugin that can do this, do recommend. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, using Dynamic.ooo is a good idea in sense of having Logical forms. But i am not sure if it can save the form in db...but i am sure that you can set it so that the forms are sent to your selected email. I myself have found this plugin amazingly handy, give it a try!

Comment: Thanks Mhdi. I will try it out.Much appreciated.

Comment: Here is a toturial on saving forms to db using Dynamic.ooo, i just found it. https://www.dynamic.ooo/tutorial/elementor-form-save-to-database/

Comment: Is there now a better way to do it directly with Elementor Pro? Can it's dynamic fields directly interface with a mysql database and pick values from the database table?